# GUI Freezzes when opening a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, arduino, serial-communication

I'm sure this is one of the worst codes you have ever seen but this is my first object oriented program.
This program should communicate with an Arduino to collect informations about a solar array and some batteries. It will have also to automatically manage some inverters and so on.
I have removed the most part of the GUI to make the code a little bit easier to be read but it is still quite big.
What I have tried to code is something that once the serial communication starts  let me change the parameters on the GUI, I tried to realize this by opening a new thread that works in the background and collects or sends the data.
What actually happens is that as soon as the serial communication starts the GUI freezes and after a while everything chrashes.
I added a print inside the thread to check if the comunications starts and actually before python chrashes some informations are gathered from the serial port.

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox
import ttk
import serial
import sys
import glob
import threading
from time import sleep


class PaginaPrincipale(Tkinter.Tk, threading.Thread):
    dati_in = None
    dati_out = None

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        si1 = Tkinter.IntVar()
        au1 = Tkinter.IntVar()
        si2 = Tkinter.IntVar()
        au2 = Tkinter.IntVar()

        self.grid()

        # those classes will manage the auto function
        def manuale(variable):
            if variable == 1:
                print(si1.get())
            if variable == 2:
                print(si2.get())

        def automatico(variable):
            if variable == 1:
                print(au1.get())
            if variable == 2:
                print(au2.get())

        # this class manages the serial connection, it scans for the available ports
        # and when the user select the desired one it should open it and start a thread
        # I still haven't implemented the update of the GUI
        def connetti():

            # Here I extract the clicked value on the listbox
            def selezione(evt):
                w = evt.widget
                index = int(w.curselection()[0])
                value = w.get(index)
                scelta_box.config(text=value)

            # Here I try to open the selected port and to start a new thread which keeps exchanging
            # information with the microcontroller (Arduino)
            def avvia_seriale(porta):
                try:
                    print(porta)
                    pagina_connessione.destroy()
                    threading.Thread(target=comunicazione(porta))

                except:
                    # Here PiCharm gives me a warning: too broad exception clause
                    tkMessageBox.showerror('Serial port', 'Can''t open the selected serial port')
                    pass

            # here I will place all the serial communication statements
            def comunicazione(porta):
                porta_seriale = serial.Serial(porta)
                while porta_seriale.isOpen():
                    porta_seriale.write(1)
                    sleep(.1)
                    self.dati_in = porta_seriale.readline()
                    sleep(.1)
                    print self.dati_in
                pass

            # Here I scan for available ports and I put them inside the listbox
            if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
                ports = ['COM%s' % (i + 1) for i in range(256)]
            elif sys.platform.startswith('linux') or sys.platform.startswith('cygwin'):
                # this excludes your current terminal "/dev/tty"
                ports = glob.glob('/dev/tty[A-Za-z]*')
            elif sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
                ports = glob.glob('/dev/tty.*')
            else:
                raise EnvironmentError('Unsupported platform')

            result = []
            for port in ports:
                try:
                    s = serial.Serial(port)
                    s.close()
                    result.append(port)  # il metodo append() aggiunge alla lista result l'ultimo termine trovato
                except (OSError, serial.SerialException):
                    pass

            # I open a new toplevel so that when I choose and open the serial port I close it and nothing remains
            # on the main page
            pagina_connessione = Tkinter.Toplevel()
            pagina_connessione.title('Gestione connessione')

            descrizione_scelte = Tkinter.Label(pagina_connessione, text='Lista scelte:', justify='left')
            descrizione_scelte.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='W')
            lista_scelte = Tkinter.Listbox(pagina_connessione, height=len(result), selectmode='single')
            contatore = len(result)
            for item in result:
                lista_scelte.insert(contatore, item)
                contatore += 1

            if contatore == 0:
                lista_scelte.insert(0, 'Nessuna porta seriale')

            lista_scelte.grid(column=0, row=1)
            lista_scelte.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', selezione)

            bottone_connessione = Tkinter.Button(pagina_connessione, text='Connetti!',
                                                 command=lambda: avvia_seriale(scelta_box.cget("text")))
            bottone_connessione.grid(column=1, row=1)

            scelta_box = Tkinter.Label(pagina_connessione, width=15, height=1, borderwidth=3, background='blue')
            scelta_box.grid(column=0, row=2)

            pagina_connessione.mainloop()

        #
        #
        # This is the main GUI
        #
        #
        frame_batteria1 = Tkinter.Frame(self, borderwidth=2, bg="black")
        frame_batteria1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='news')

        self.descrittore_v_b_1 = Tkinter.Label(frame_batteria1, text="V Batteria 1", font=("Helvetica", 8),
                                               justify='center')
        self.descrittore_v_b_1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='news')
        self.descrittore_i_b_1 = Tkinter.Label(frame_batteria1, text="I Batteria 1", font=("Helvetica", 8),
                                               justify='center')
        self.descrittore_i_b_1.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='NEWS')

        self.vbatteria1 = Tkinter.Scale(frame_batteria1, bd=4, troughcolor='blue', resolution=0.1, state='disabled',
                                        from_=15, to=0)
        self.vbatteria1.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='NEWS')
        self.ibatteria1 = Tkinter.Scale(frame_batteria1, bd=4, troughcolor='blue', resolution=0.1, state='disabled',
                                        from_=10, to=0)
        self.ibatteria1.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky='NEWS')

        self.descrittore_inverter1 = Tkinter.Label(self, text="Inverter 1", font=("Helvetica", 8), justify='left')
        self.descrittore_inverter1.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky='NEWS')

        self.scelte_manuali_inverter1 = Tkinter.Radiobutton(self, text="Acceso", variable=si1, value=1,
                                                            command=lambda: manuale(1))
        self.scelte_manuali_inverter1.grid(column=0, row=4, sticky='NEWS')
        self.scelte_manuali_inverter1 = Tkinter.Radiobutton(self, text="Spento", variable=si1, value=0,
                                                            command=lambda: manuale(1))
        self.scelte_manuali_inverter1.grid(column=0, row=5, sticky='NEWS')

        self.scelta_automatica_inverter1 = Tkinter.Checkbutton(self, text="Automatico", variable=au1, onvalue=1,
                                                               offvalue=0, command=lambda: automatico(1))
        self.scelta_automatica_inverter1.grid(column=2, row=4, sticky='NEWS')

        #
        #
        # separators
        #
        #
        ttk.Separator(self, orient='horizontal').grid(row=6, columnspan=8, sticky='EW')
        ttk.Separator(self, orient='vertical').grid(row=2, column=3, rowspan=4, sticky='NS')

        self.gestisci_connessione = Tkinter.Button(self, text="Connetti!", command=connetti)
        self.gestisci_connessione.grid(row=7, column=6, sticky='EW')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    applicazione = PaginaPrincipale(None)
    applicazione.title('Pannello di controllo')
    applicazione.mainloop()
```

Comment: you can't use `while` loop because it blocks `mainloop` which does everething in Tkinter (and any other GUI) - it gets key/mouse event, sends it to widgets, changes data in widgets, and redraws widgets. You can use `root.after(millisecond, function_name)` to run some function periodically and "simulate" `while` loop. Or you could use `root.update()` in you loop to force mainloop to does one loop.

Comment: But why the while loop blocks the mailnoop if i placed it in a new thread?
If I understood your answer with your command in theory I could remove the thread right?

Comment: simple example: [read serial in tkinter](https://github.com/furas/my-python-codes/blob/master/tkinter/read-serial-port/main.py)

Answer (score 2):

You run thread in wrong way. Now you have

```
threading.Thread(target=comunicazione(porta))
```

But `target=` expects function name - it means without `()` and arguments.

So you run `comunicazione(porta)` as normal function in main thread and when function returns something then it will be assigned to `target=`. But function never stops and blocks main thread.

You can use `lambda` to create function without arguments and assign to variable.

```
threading.Thread(target=lambda:comunicazione(porta))
```

But you have to use `your_thread.start()` to run thread ie.

```
t = threading.Thread(target=lambda:comunicazione(porta))
t.start()
```

Comment: Now it works. Thank you! 
Should I take care of the warning on the `avvia_seriale(porta)` exception or I can ignore it?

Comment: you could at least `print()` it - sometimes it can be usefull information.